# Where are Ceph clusters

Tags: cloud, openstack, ceph

I am new to Ceph. I wanted to know where are ceph data stored (I am not refering to OSDs). I mean is it stored on some remote data center ? If yes, are there any remote storage limits or I can put any amount of data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ceph generally stores data onto local disks of the machine/machines which are part of the cluster, based on the configuration.

I think this is what you are looking for.
https://ceph.com/geen-categorie/ceph-osd-where-is-my-data/

Answer (score 0):

In `ceph` Some configuration and data are stored in every single cluster nodes depend on their functionality. Configuration are stored in `/etc/ceph` and data in `/var/lib/ceph`.